# How can one have eternal life by the death of Jesus or by Jesus teachings?

Tags: catholicism, christology, jehovahs-witnesses, global-christianity, catholic-bible

Before the death of Jesus, Jesus was teaching the birth of eternal life(birth of the Spirit) which steps are not completely describe by the four gospel (Matthew, mark, Luke, and john). On several note he ask them to believe in him and his teachings.  Now what was he teaching in terms of procedure so that one can follow and learn, secondly are people granted eternal live by his teaching or by his death on the cross? This is my question. I believed he was killed because of what he thought which contradict their believes and as a result he was killed for his teachings. This teaching is what will save man from sin or second death, and not the death of Jesus which only came as a consequence of his teachings.
The Buddha also went in his time about teaching enlightenment (birth of the Spirit) but what he taught is not found in most book except the word "he went about teaching them) but later on we learn he was teaching them a meditation technique for seekers of truth/enlightenment but these technique is only known to few masters and devotees. 
Now could Jesus be teaching similar knowledge? On a certain occasion Jesus told Nicodemus how to receive eternal life, which he said Nicodemus must be born of the Spirit, and not believing that he Jesus will die and rise again. But how to be born of the Spirit the bible didn't say in the four gospel after he spoke with Nicodemus. He told the Samaritan women that he will give her the living water(Teach her the birth of the  Spirit) and she will taste nor more(die no more) again the bible didn't let us know how or if Jesus gave the woman the living water. He told a certain rich man to renounce his earthly desire and follow him. On these note he was given the teachings of eternal life. Now why does the church say by just confession that Jesus died on the cross and rose from the grave and repentance (Church ideal of burn) man will be save? Is that what Jesus taught the people about eternal life before he died?

Comment: I think your question is very broad, covers a very large scope, is actually multiple questions coalesced together and is impossible to answer given the nature of the website. This website considers _comparative_ questions, within the context of the wide range of beliefs held by the many who take the name 'Christ'.

Comment: Do not ask random people on the internet about these things. Go find a Christian who you trust and ask them.

Comment: I have not seen one, that's why I came on the internet.

Comment: Where are you in the world? It's extremely likely there is a church near you.

Comment: Here are some articles that you might find helpful: https://www.gotquestions.org/why-Jesus-die.html https://www.gotquestions.org/Jesus-died-for-our-sins.html https://www.gotquestions.org/death-resurrection-Christ.html

Answer (score 1):

Christians have different views about salvation, but there is one thing that is believed by virtually every denomination - salvation does not come about simply through the teachings of Jesus. Hearing Jesus teaching and putting it into practice may lead you to salvation, but salvation comes through the death and resurrection of Jesus. If this were not so there would have been no need for Jesus to die.

Going into more detail would lead us to disagreement within this forum.

Comment: Jesus' death and resurrection was the sacrifice through which salvation was made possible, but surely we still should be following Jesus' teachings and not be led into temptations

Comment: Jesus was trying to established something and they killed him because they don't understand him. How would such death lead to salvation? I still hold that the practice of the teachings is what is of importance, but what did he teach is another question

Comment: Christians believe that there is more to Jesus' death than that.